# Why do I see this strange behavior in my React/TypeScript/MUI Dialog?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a dialog that comes up in the flow of a React/TypeScript/MUI application that presents several buttons. As you select each button the dialog function adds the value of the button to a state array and removes it from the dialog. It's sort of working, by that I mean that the initial dialog looks fine, but after the first button press the original dialog remains in the background and a new dialog appears on top of it. With each subsequent button press the top dialog works correctly. Could someone please explain why the original dialog is showing up in the background?
[The dialog on dialog effect][[image: The dialog on dialog effect]]

Here's my dialog code:

```
import { useContext, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { AppContext } from "../AppContextProvider";
import { Button, Dialog, DialogTitle, Snackbar, styled } from "@mui/material";
import { grey } from "@mui/material/colors";
import { allGearEffectTypes, GearEffectType, GearType } from "../CharStore/CharData";

const StyledButton = styled(Button)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: "black",
  backgroundColor: grey[400],
  borderRadius: 25,
  '&:hover': {
    backgroundColor: grey[500],
  }
}));

type AddGearEffectProps = {
  openDlg: boolean,
  closeDlg: (effects?: Array<GearEffectType> | null) => void;
}

const AddGearEffectDlg = (props: AddGearEffectProps) => {
  const {openDlg, closeDlg} = props;
  const [char, setChar] = useContext(AppContext)!;
  const [gearEffects, setGearEffects] = useState<Array<GearEffectType> | null>(null);

  const effectButtons = useMemo(() => {
    const effectButtons: Array<React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>> = [];
    allGearEffectTypes.forEach((effectType, index) => {
      if (!gearEffects || !(gearEffects.includes(effectType))) {
        effectButtons.push(
          <StyledButton key={index} onClick={() => handleAddEffect(effectType)} variant="contained" sx={{ marginTop: 1, marginLeft: 1, marginRight: 1 }}>{effectType}</StyledButton>
        );
      } else {
        effectButtons.push(<StyledButton key={index} disabled={true} variant="contained" sx={{ marginTop: 1, marginLeft: 1, marginRight: 1 }}>{effectType}</StyledButton>)
      }
    });
    return effectButtons;
  }, [char, gearEffects]);

  const handleAddEffect = (effectType: GearEffectType) => {
    const newEffects: Array<GearEffectType> = gearEffects ? [...gearEffects] : [];
    newEffects.push(effectType);
    setGearEffects(newEffects);
    // closeDlg(newEffects); // Close the dialog after adding the effect
  }

  const handleCloseAddGearEffectDlg =  () => {
    closeDlg(gearEffects);
  }
  
  return (
    <Dialog onClose={handleCloseAddGearEffectDlg} open={openDlg}>
      <DialogTitle style={{ marginTop: -10, marginBottom: -20 }}>Pick Effect to add</DialogTitle>
      <>
        {effectButtons}
      </>
      <StyledButton onClick={handleCloseAddGearEffectDlg} sx={{ marginTop: 1, marginBottom: 1, marginLeft: 1, marginRight: 1 }}>Close</StyledButton>
    </Dialog>
  );
}

export default AddGearEffectDlg;
```

I apologize for the delay Ryan, I'm working crazy hours and falling down tired. I do have a codesandbox but it's the whole app. It'll take me awhile to get it paired down (I really need some sleep) but if you do want to see it now it's here:
[CodeSandbox project](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/dirkwiggley/savage-tracker/main?workspaceId=fe2c9f73-1638-45ca-992e-3218aa4b4c6a)

In order to replicate the error, you'd click the down button on the panels until you get to the Gear panel (the last one) at that point you're in the src/Components/Gear/GearPanel.tsx file. When you click the Add Gear button that opens the New Gear Name Dialog. When you add a name (any) and click the Select button, you'll be in the src/Components/Gear/AddGearEffectDlg.tsx file. GearPanel.tsx is the parent and AddGearEffectDlg.tsx is the child.

What's happening in AddGearEffect is that there's an initial list of gear effects you can add and as you select them, they disappear off the dialog and are added to an state variable that supposed to be passed back to the parent when AddGearEffectDlg closes. The initial AddGearEffectDlg has all of the gear effects, but when you select the first one it appears as though a second AddGearEffectDlg is opened on top of that one with the correct list (missing the selected effect). For each effect selected after that, the new dialog's list shrinks appropriately however, the original AddGearEffectDlg is there in the background.

The parent, GearPanel.tsx, has three different dialogs that it's supposed to go through in sequence. NewGearNameDlg.tsx, AddGearEffectDlg, and AddGearValueDlg. It tracks this by having a state variable, currentStep, which is either NAME_STEP, EFFECT_STEP, VALUE_STEP, or UNKOWN_STEP. It uses these states to dictate which dialog should be open by setting the correct states of openNewGearNameDlg, openAddGearEffectDlg, and openAddGearValueDlg, and is supposed to ensure that only one of those dialogs is open by setting them all when the dialogs are supposed to be swapped. Each of these dialogs has a close dialog method passed in to them that is used to call back into the parent to set the data that they gathered and to tell the parent to swap to the next dialog if appropriate.

Sorry if that's a bit rambling. I'm on about 2 hours sleep in the last 40 so I'll stop typing here.

So, after some fussing around with the code I change the memoized code that generates effects buttons in AddGearEffectDlg from this:

```
  const effectButtons = useMemo(() => {
    const effectButtons: Array<React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>> = [];
    allGearEffectTypes.forEach((effectType, index) => {
      if (!gearEffects || !(gearEffects.includes(effectType))) {
        effectButtons.push(
          <StyledButton key={index} onClick={() => handleAddEffect(effectType)} variant="contained" sx={{ marginTop: 1, marginLeft: 1, marginRight: 1 }}>{effectType}</StyledButton>
        );
      }
    });
    return effectButtons;
  }, [char, gearEffects]);
```

To this:

```
  const effectButtons = useMemo(() => {
    const effectButtons: Array<React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>> = [];
    allGearEffectTypes.forEach((effectType, index) => {
      if (!gearEffects || !(gearEffects.includes(effectType))) {
        effectButtons.push(
          <StyledButton key={index} onClick={() => handleAddEffect(effectType)} variant="contained" sx={{ marginTop: 1, marginLeft: 1, marginRight: 1 }}>{effectType}</StyledButton>
        );
      } else {
        effectButtons.push(<StyledButton key={index} disabled={true} variant="contained" sx={{ marginTop: 1, marginLeft: 1, marginRight: 1 }}>{effectType}</StyledButton>)
      }
    });
    return effectButtons;
  }, [char, gearEffects]);
```

Which does what I was looking to do in the first place, which is make buttons unselectable after using them once. It is entirely possible that the original dialog is still hiding behind what is being displayed but since this is a modal, I can't see it (which after all the time we've put in I can live with). This is not ideal, but liveable. If anyone has more thoughts, I'm all ears (eyes?). :)

I'm not going to accept my solution here as I did not actually solve the problem. I effectively hid the problem. If anyone has a real solution, I would love to give you credit for figuring it out!

Comment: The dialog code isn't enough for people to help. The problem is going to be in the code that renders the dialog. Presumably you are rendering multiple instances of it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ryan. I did just that. Let me know what you think.

Comment: There isn't anything that jumps out at me with the code you have shown so far. A code sandbox with the minimal code needed to reproduce the problem would help considerably.

Comment: Looks like you are not closing the previous dialogue when you click new. either close previous or keep a single dialogue component and render content conditionally

Comment: I had a lot to add to the explanation for Ryan and couldn't fit it in one comment so I added it to the original post.

Comment: Akhil, I'm sorry I don't know what you mean by clicking new. There's no new button in this process. There is only one AddGearEffectDlg in the parent GearPanel (see above). If you're seeing something I'm missing, please explain. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i think issue is that the closeDlg function which is responsible for closing the dialog, is not being called after the first button press. This prevents the original dialog from being closed and causes it to remain visible.
try tis way

```
const handleAddEffect = (effectType: GearEffectType) => {
  const newEffects: Array<GearEffectType> = gearEffects ? [...gearEffects] : [];
  newEffects.push(effectType);
  setGearEffects(newEffects);
  closeDlg(newEffects); // Close the dialog after adding the effect
}
```

and let me know if any .

Comment: Howdy Rainy, that does work and for the time being I will add that call to closeDlg. I was hoping to allow a user to select multiple effects to add to equipment (i.e. a flaming sword does physical damage and magic damage) so the intent is to be able to select effects several times and use an array of effects in the next dialog to set each effects values. For some reason, this works on the second selection and each selection thereafter but not on the first. I am beyond puzzled by this.

Comment: i am happy to see it working , i didn't go through the updated code but i can say this issue could be same as this one and cause by the incorrect order of operation.

Comment: Hey Rainy, did you mean to include a link to a similar issue that might be relevant? If so I'd like to read that.

Comment: I did make one more change that I edited into the original post that allows a user to pick multiple items. It doesn't remove buttons from the dialog but it does disable them. The dialog remains the same size, so maybe there's still another dialog hiding behind that we can't see. But since the list of buttons isn't too large, it's not the worst solution.